# Why would one use the ChannelFactory to instantiate a WCF proxy rather than a Service Reference?

Tags: c#, wcf

There seem to be two ways to instantiate WCF service proxies described [here](http://bit.ly/v0wmN2). My question is why would one want to use the ChannelFactory to instantiate a WCF proxy and what are the benefits of this approach?

I've met people with a strong opinion on the second option but I cannot manage to understand a clear argumentation from them

Comment: Please explain what the "second option" is supposed to be. There's more than two options to create a WCF proxy.

Comment: I try but stack doesn't allow me to post the link

Comment: I'm intrigued what the link *is* now, as a 730-rep user should be **more** than able to post links. Could you run the link via bit.ly please, so we can see it?

Comment: There _are_ two options in the link... see first sentence. In brief, use a Service Reference or use a ChannelFactory.

Comment: @Jeremy, the question is why would one want to use a ChannelFactory, I would edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: is there would be any difference in terms of performance when we use channel factory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using assembly-sharing (which is, let's face it, hugely convenient if you own both ends of the pipe), then both ends already have a complete version if the interface etc. It seems redundant to run the svcutil tool (at command-prompt or via the IDE) just to get back a wrapper for what we already have. It also works very well when you want to code only to an interface, not to the wrapper class - and use some centralised code to get a channel to a particular interface at a given address. This is actually how I mainly use WCF.

The "client" approach works well for one-off services, or where it doesn't need to go through any central tooling. It also makes for very simple demos.

Comment: Do you create a separate project for the interfaces when you own both ends of the pipe?

Comment: @Hohhi yes, I'd put that in a library (dll) typically. Sometimes the same program is both a client and server, but that is pretty rare.

Comment: having two projects and a project for hosting and DI seem to be an overkill for a small and medium size projects from my point of view

Comment: @Hohhi I only mentioned 3 projects; a client project, a server project, and a DTO/interface library. You almost certainly have 2 of those 3, and the 3rd is not unreasonable.

Comment: is there would be any difference in terms of performance when we use channel factory?

Answer (score 4):

The first option uses configuration settings provided in the `web.config` / `app.config` files to instantiate a proxy, however in certain situations its not feasible to put these settings in that file, for example if your application needs to use a different binding (maybe HTTP vs Named Pipes) depending on the scenario, or possibly your application may not even have a .config file.

The second option gives a lot more flexibility when creating proxies to programatically specify the configuration to use for each proxy as you instantiate it.

---

To give a more concrete example, supposing you wish to use Named Pipes for communication if communicating with the local machine, and HTTP if communicating with a remote host:

```
if (UseNamedPipes())
{
    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/Simple/BankService");
    return ChannelFactory<IBank>.CreateChannel(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), address);
}
else
{
    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/Simple/BankService");
    return ChannelFactory<IBank>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), address);
}
```

Comment: What are the **certain** situations? I want to understand what are they because you are not the dirst to mention them

Comment: is there would be any difference in terms of performance when we use channel factory?

Answer (score 2):

One of the specific cases would while developing any office add-in or visual studio add-in projects where you don't have the app.config file.

Also , lets say in an organisation where you want to standardise on certain bindings and certain endpoint security patterns. you would want to create an API which developers can easily use to create a proxy, in this case you would encapsulate all the binding information using channelfactory.