# consuming wsdl service with out adding reference

Tags: c#, service, wsdl

There is a service running locally on a machine I have the address to the wsdl. I know in visual studio c# you can add a reference to the service address is there any way to consume/make the calls to the service in c# with out adding it as a reference?

Comment: Basically with WSDL you get meta data and contracts between client and service which you can always create directly at client end without adding service reference (which eventually end up with adding relevant and required metadata). However when you do yourself, you always in more control (like logging, error handling etc.) For example : we use WCF channel factory and shared contracts to establish connection between client and server.

Comment: do you use any special namespaces to accomplish this? or is it all native within the .NET framework? do you have an example on how to connect to a service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048992/why-would-one-use-the-channelfactory-to-instantiate-a-wcf-proxy-rather-than-a-se might help you